# Standardising DEM raster for a MCE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, raster-calculator

I'm trying to complete a Multi-Criteria Evaluation for an MSc assessment and am in the process of standardising my factor maps.  Unfortunately, my DEM layer (ASCII file) keeps changing from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The syntax used in Raster Calculator is: *(“DEM” – 0) / (544 – 0)* where DEM is the layer, 0 is the minimum values and 544 is the max value.

Has anyone come across this before? Does anyone know how to standardise it so the surface variation is still present?

I've done the same for Topographic Wetness Index but that's done ok (both layers are visualised the same)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what your table of contents looks like? Or your symbology properties?  My first thought is that there might be something that needs changed with your display properties, similar to this question here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127696/querying-slope-data-using-raster-calculator-why-are-all-results-true

Comment: Done.  Thank you, I've taken a look at that post.  My problem is that I need to standardise the DEM from 0-544 to 0-1.  The syntax keeps creating a 0 or 1 value instead.  I've only just started with GIS so am not that experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default the output raster will be integer type. You must convert to float in order to have decimal output, or multiply by 100 to have percentage

```
Float(“DEM” – 0) / (544 – 0)

(100*(“DEM” – 0)) / (544 – 0)
```

As a remark, for normalizing, you can compute min and max on the fly as in my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116910/what-special-values-can-be-included-in-the-con-tools-conditional-statement/116925#116925)

```
Float(“DEM” – "DEM".minimum) / (“DEM”.maximum – "DEM".minimum)
```

Comment: Multiplying by 100 seems to have worked, thank you.  I can now standardise the rest of my layers to be on the same scale.  The float syntax didn't seem to work in the calculator, it threw up a processing error.

Comment: Float syntax is case sensitive